# My latex file is missing

Tags: winedt, ctex

I do not know whether it is proper to ask a technical question here. It made me frustrated.
When I was writting the latex, something is wrong and it had no response. I restart the computure, the content in the latex is all zeros. Something like this
`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
The size of the file is still there. Can I recover my latex content?  Thanks.

Comment: this is really a question about your editor (I assume winedt as you tagged the question with that) some editors save recent edits of files with extensions such as `~` or `.bak` I do not know if winedt does. But otherwise if your file is really full of zero bytes you will need to restore from a backup, latex can not help at all.

Comment: I have tried to find .bak, but they are gone. I wonder whether I can recover file some time ago.